# How to populate a database from a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

im trying to pass data from a txt file an array, the txt file format is like this:

RN7101|PRO-173|14148|order-261606|MADE IN XX|ROY/WHT|_2309483380|00031|N
RN7101|PRO-173|14148|order-261606|MADE IN XX|ROY/WHT|_2309483381|00031|N
RN7101|PRO-173|14148|order-261606|MADE IN XX|ROY/WHT|_2309483382|00031|N
RN7101|PRO-173|14148|order-261606|MADE IN XX|ROY/WHT|_2309483383|00031|N

is a lot of txt files with the same data chain. Any file can have one line to many.
im trying to do a WPF form to update a database.

Comment: Read the information in said text file. Write read information to the database.

Comment: do you know any method that i can use??

Comment: That *is* a method - and it's done by using the appropriate API (and "glue" logic code) for the relevant operations. E.g. ref. [Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302325.aspx) (or existing abstractions over such) ..

Comment: You question as originally written shows no knowledge of anything regarding what you're doing. Stack Overflow is not designed to write people's code for them. You need to give us something you tried, and didn't work. Put some effort into it. If you don't know where to start, this is unfortunately not the place to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sebastien Lorion's Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), then use the class [`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to blast the data into your table.

`Lumenworks.Framework.IO.Csv.CsvReader` is an `IDataReader`: an instance of it can be supplied to the method [`SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx).

It's about that simple.